# Aligning formulas in specific way

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
L(r)&=\sum \limits_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}|\{(x_1,\dots,y_3)\in \mathcal{E}^6: y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_1=y_{2}-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_{2}=a,\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_2=\\
    &y_{3}-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_{3}=b, \ x_1\neq x_{2},\ x_2\neq x_3\}|=\\
    &=\sum \limits_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum \limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)=
\end{split}    
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The above code represents the following formula:

[image]

So my I was wondering is it possible to move the second line a bit right so that it starts under the highlighted colon?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code,as is, cannot be compiled. Could you please post a *complete*  code?

Comment: @Bernard, Sorry about that! I've edited, please try again.

Comment: I tried again, but the same problem:  where does the `\mathds` command come from?

Comment: @Bernard, I am so sorry! I guess I fixed it now.

Comment: @Bernard, Does it work now?

Comment: Yes. No problem: the `doublestroke` package was installed on my system.

Comment: @Bernard, I was wondering do you know how to answer my question?

Comment: I thought of using the `alignat*`environment, but unfortunately each time   I try to add new line (to do it progressively), I have an error message saying that the paragraph ended before alignat* was finished, and  don't see why I obtain this message.

Comment: @Bernard, I see. Maybe someone else knows to do this. Let's wait

Comment: @Bernard did you perhaps leave an entire blank line? AMS equation environments cannot have any blank lines. If you want to leave space to type, leave a `%` sign in those lines so you don't accidentally start a new paragraph.

Comment: @WillieWong ;  No, but I wonder whether there are some hidden characters, as it happens some times.

Answer (score 3):

The following is more legible than what you had in mind. I also removed some spurious `=` signs. As well as the calls of `\limits` which are not doing anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
        L(r)&= \sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\left|\left\{(x_1,\dots,y_3)\in \mathcal{E}^6: \begin{array}{l}y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_1=y_{2}-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_{2}=a,\\
y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_2=y_{3}-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_{3}=b, \\ x_1\neq x_{2},\ x_2\neq x_3 \end{array}\right\}\right|\\
    &=\sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)
\end{split}    
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can slightly improve the output more by including some `\vphantoms` in the subscript of the first summation symbol on the second line so that they line up better with the remainder summations.

```
&=\sum_{\substack{\vphantom{y_2\sqrt{r}}\theta_1,\theta_2\\ \vphantom{\theta_2y_2\sqrt{r}}a,b}} ...
```

would give you the slightly more pleasant (compare to the previous image where the first set of subscripts are shifted up compared to the second)

[image]

(Unfortunately, since you used `\substack`, the `mathtools` `\adjustlimits` doesn't quite do the job.)

(Depending your aesthetics, you may want to also use `\smashoperator[r]` on the three inner summations so that the expressions take up less space overall. See the `mathtools` documentation for more details.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks really nice! I did not understand the essense of `\vphantoms`. Your second picture of enlarged summation looks like mine summation. What is the difference?

Comment: In the first image (as in yours), the \theta_1, \theta_2 beneath the summation symbol is placed higher than the line y_2 - \sqrt{r} \theta_1 x_2 beneath the second summation symbol. And the a,b beneath the first summation symbol is significantly higher than the second line beneath the second summation symbol. In the second image that got fixed.

Comment: Basically, each line in the subscript of the second summation symbol is reserved more vertical space because of the square root symbol (which is taller than \theta) and the y (which has a tail). The \vphantom asks LaTeX to pretend those characters are present also (even though they aren't) so that the line spacing are computed based on the larger spacing of those taller lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explnanation! I was wondering why `\vpantoms` is not working in my case?

Comment: @ZFR: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by `\vphantom` not working?

Comment: Sorry for confusing question. I mean I copied `&=\sum_{\substack{\vphantom{y_2\sqrt{r}}\theta_1,\theta_2\\ \vphantom{\theta_2y_2\sqrt{r}}a,b}} ...` and my overleaf is not compilating it. Is there any mistake in this code?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message but it does not show the indices of the summation.

Comment: I was wondering can you show how to apply `\vphantom` in this formula `\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_2,b}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\mathds{1}_{\{b\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)\right)`

Comment: If there are no error messages I cannot help, as it would likely be an issue with Overleaf and not with the code. I copied that code directly from the tile I used to generate the picture.

Comment: Can you help with my previous comment?

Comment: For what you just asked, the `\adjustlimits` command from `mathtools` should work (to a degree). The `\vphantom` call is due to the presence of the substack, which meant that in addition to adjusting the distance to the bottom of the summation sign we also need to adjust the distance between the two lines in the substack. Since in this latter expression the first sum only has one row of subscript, that is not an issue. You should look at its documentation to see how `\adjustlimits` is used.

Comment: I am a bit confused with you wrote

Comment: @ZFR: please open the documentation for `mathtools`. Look for `\adjustlimits`. See what it is designed for. In the context of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650780/aligning-formulas-in-specific-way/650798?noredirect=1#comment1622306_650798 that should **just work**. The reason it doesn't work in the answer above is that I wanted to simultaneously line up both lines of the `\substack`s from the two summation signs. The way `\adjustlimits` works it only takes care of lining up one of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Willie's Wong recommendation of an alternative approach, I would like to solve the original problem, since it might be useful to know in general.

Anytime you need to nested alignments, you can make use of `aligned` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
L(r)&=\begin{aligned}[t]
        \sum \limits_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}|\{(x_1,\dots,y_3)\in \mathcal{E}^6: &y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_1=y_{2}-\sqrt{r}\theta_1 x_{2}=a,\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_2=\\[-4ex]
        &y_{3}-\sqrt{r}\theta_2 x_{3}=b, \ x_1\neq x_{2},\ x_2\neq x_3\}|=
    \end{aligned}\\[1ex]
    &=\sum \limits_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum \limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)=
\end{split}    
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```